# Filter gender in an ecommerce site with ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Im totally new to programming, i'am making an ecommerce site and i have to filter the gender of clothes by Male or Female if it is possible to do.
I am using react and redux!

++++++++++++

```
 class ProductList extends Component {
    state = {
        slug: 'Products'
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='itemlist'>
                {
                    this.props.theItems.items.map(item => <Product item={item}/>)
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return{
         theItems: state.items
    }

}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ProductList)
```

```
const Product = ({ item, addToCart }) => {

    return (
        <div className='itemcard'>
            <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
                <Card.Img variant="top" src={item.img} />
                <Card.Body>
                    <Card.Title className='card-title'>{item.title}</Card.Title>
                    <Card.Text className='card-text'>
                        {item.description}
                        {item.price}$
                     </Card.Text>
                    <Button variant="light" onClick={() => { addToCart(item.id) }} >Add to cart</Button>
                </Card.Body>
            </Card>

        </div>
    )
}

export default connect(null, {addToCart})(Product)
```

This is my Data file in the reducer, i have to add the gender attribute here?
Thank you for your answer

```
    items: [
            {
                id: uuid(),
                img: 'https://images.thejacketmaker.com/Men%27s+Noah+Black+Leather+Biker+Jacket1-4-1557058576770',
                title: 'Noah Black Leather Biker Jacket',
                description: '',
                price: '230'
            },
            {
                id: uuid(),
                img: 'https://images.thejacketmaker.com/Men%27s+Lavendard+Brown+Leather+Biker+Jacket7846-4-1577528725717.jpg',
                title: 'Lavendard Brown Leather Biker Jacket',
                description: '',
                price: '230'
            },
            {
                id: uuid(),
                img: 'https://images.thejacketmaker.com/Men%27s+Bomia+Ma-1+Brown+Leather+Bomber+Jacket7819-4-1579778569432.jpg',
                title: 'Bomia Ma-1 Brown Leather Bomber Jacket',
                description: '',
                price: '265'
            }
```

Comment: Please provide more information on what you want to do. This way its almost impossible to give a constructive answer.

Comment: This has actually nothing to do with your code and is total offtopic. Nevertheless: From a non-binary and gender-nonconforming perspective it would be nice to choose between 'feminine, masculine and unisex'. For many people like me it's quite annoying to always choose between 'male and female'. Just a suggestion. :)

Comment: What exactly does your data look like which contains information of the gender?

Comment: I posted my data in the question, do i have to add the gender attribute there?

Answer (score 0):

Your question lacks of information, but assuming that items are products with a `gender` attribute that can be either `Male` or `Female`, you could do something like that:

```
 class ProductList extends Component {
    state = {
        slug: 'Products'
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='itemlist'>
                {
                    this.props.theItems.items
                         .filter(item => item.gender === 'Male')
                         .map(item => <Product item={item}/>)
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return{
         theItems: state.items
    }

}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ProductList)
```

To understand how it works, check the docs about [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method.